# Tab Bar Selected Index for More Tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Anyone Know how to get the selected index for a controller in the tab bar?? I'm trying to get it to make a force touch quick action to a controller in the more section but nothing I'm doing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITabbarController` has a following properties that help you to get selected tab index & view controller also:

- [selectedIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621171-selectedindex): Provides an index of the view controller associated with the currently selected tab item.
  `var selectedIndex: Int { get set }`
- [selectedViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller): view controller associated with the currently selected tab item. 
  `unowned(unsafe) var selectedViewController: UIViewController? { get set }`

You can also get selected tabbar index & controller using `UITabBarControllerDelegate` methods:

- [tabBarController(_:didSelect:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller): Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar.

Here is full reference documentation on [UITabbarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use below:-

```
var selectedIndex: Int { get set }
```